# Apache structure and config for React app with self hosted headless CMS

Tags: reactjs, apache, content-management-system, headless

I want to build a React powered app that uses a self hosted instance of [Cockpit](https://getcockpit.com/) to fetch data and host both on an Apache server.

I'm familiar with installing Cockpit to the default `DocumentRoot`, but I'm not sure where to put the frontend files. I don't want to just messily dump them in the same folder, since there'd probably be also conflicts with Cockpit files.

How can I seperate both apps in a clean way and tell Apache to serve them correctly?

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research with more specific keywords, I found the answer myself:

Basically you want to create folders for both app and API (i.e. Cockpit) in your `DocumentRoot`. Then you are able to set Virtual Hosts in your Apache configuration like this (assuming your folders are named `client` and `server` and your `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html/`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/client"
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/server"
    ServerName api.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

API calls can then be made via the `api.example.com` subdomain.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html for more examples.